# Want to add chatbot I have api (hosted) on trello cards( list of cards) when comment on card give response to that comment in same card with cha

Tags: automation, openai-api, trello

So basically when user add comment on card I have a link with post req in which I want to trigger webhook something with that comment data and then send response again to that card under thaq question comment with creating new comment.

But catch is I have list of cards want to apply same on every cards.

I'm thinking to work with webhooks like trigger webhook when comments add something like that